# Как сделать обработку получаемого значения для значения в массиве получаемого извне?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
const arr = {
    someKey: foreignValue[0]['key'], //В данном случае значение запрашивается из другого объекта
    someKey2: someValue2

}
```

Некоторые его значения запрашиваются из другого объекта (arr генерируется в цикле .forEach на основе другого объекта). Если значение получить не удается - приходит ошибка, что нельзя получить .key от undefined.
Мне нужно обработать эти ошибки, присваивая значения по умолчанию при их возникновении.

Как я могу это лаконично сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классика:

```
someKey: (foreignValue[0] && foreignValue[0]['key']) || default_value,
```

Современный вариант:

```
someKey: foreignValue?.[0]?.['key'] ?? default_value,
```

Comment: @nörbörnën Да, это тоже.

Comment: добавить в ваш ответ? (чтобы не плодить)

Comment: @nörbörnën Да, пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. А почему не срабатывает вариант foreignValue[0]['key'] || default_value ?

Comment: @Lumxi Потому что здесь код пытается безусловно получить значение `foreignValue[0].key` - свойство объекта `foreignValue[0]`, которого (объекта) нет.